# Is it possible to request an appeal to a rejected edit?

Tags: support, tags, editing, question-title

I suggest this edit yesterday:  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/5895

I think that it is a very substantial edit.

In first reading the title, there is a substantial difference between how to unit test and how to unit test in a specific development environment.

Also, if someone is following the visual-studio-2010 tag, then this is specifically applicable to what they are following.  If the visual-studio-2010 tag is not added to this post, then this post is not listed in their tagged items, even though this post is specifically applicable to that development environment and no other development environment.

Is there a platform or messaging system in which I can present these ideas to have the edit reconsidered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just changing the title and adding a tag isn't a "very substantial edit".

While there are differences between unit testing in general and unit testing in a specific environment, are you 100% that that's what the OP intended?

If you think that the edit is enough you can:

1. Raise a question here on meta (has you have done!)
2. Suggest the edit again. It would be worth looking for other improvements to the body of the post and explaining more clearly why you think that the edit is required in the summary.

Comment: The accepted answer (with the highest votes, as well) is specifically in response to how to set up unit testing in VS 2010.  So my rebuttal would be that perhaps OP wasn't sure how to ask what she really needed, and the thread is explicitly related to VS 2010.  If a new programmer came to this site in search for unit testing support in VS 2010, my edits would assist a new programmer in finding that thread.  I consider that very substantial, but I am OK with my opinion not being accepted.  Regardless, is there no way to appeal this edit?

Comment: @DavidKaczynski - raising it here on meta is one way to go.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you please add that to the original answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

As the person who wrote the accepted answer I'll add my 2 cents...

While the question specifically mentions VS 2010, the solution is not restricted to that version alone.  The supporting article that I referenced in the answer was written for VS 2008 and works equally as well in VS 2010 as there are no differences.

I think adding VS 2010 as a tag to the question would be a dis-service to the question.  I would consider adding the VS tag, without a version as that would be more approriate.

In either case I agree with ChrisF and ElYusubov that your edits were not substantial and additionally I would have rejected the edit as not appropriate for the question.